# How to rewrite clean url to .html in a nginx docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx

I can run nginx in a Docker container, port 4000. It should serve a static website with the following structure:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/
  index.html
  app.html
  app/
    some-other.html
```

The port was mapped to port 3000 on localhost. Now I am trying to use clean urls as following: `http://localhost:3000/app`.  However, when I try to access  this url it is redirecting me to `http://localhost:4000/app/` (notice the suffixing `/`) with status code `301 - Moved Permanently`.

I've tried using `try_files` in different locations and order (it's commented below). Nothing worked. In addition, I've also used a `rewrite` without success. Always resulting in the same redirect.

site.conf

```
server {
    listen       4000;
    server_name  localhost;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

#    location / {
#      index index.html
#      try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;
#    }

    location / {
      index index.html
      try_files $uri @htmlext $uri/;
    }

    location ~ \.html$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location @htmlext {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
    }

    error_page 404 /404;
}
```

I'd expect nginx to return the content of `app.html` without touching the url in any form. Can't I do this without adding `location /app` too?

Comment: You have two lines without terminating `;`, so they absorb the next line, which may be why your tests are not going well. The `try_files $uri @htmlext $uri/;` line is wrong anyway as the named location must be last. But the commented out block is the correct solution if you add a `;` to the previous line.

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't see this. Thank you so much, of course it's working.
*Edit:* I've moved the named location as I wanted it to be resolved before the folder. Didn't know it must be at the very end. Thanks anyways.